# Android Strudio 3.1.3 Render problem

Tags: android-studio

problemas de render, problemas con recursos privadas, con instanciaciones...en fin... en pocas palabras a  alguien mas que le sucedio esto y ya lo soluciono me puede ayudar por favor? 
una imagen habla mejor que mil palabras vean, esto es el monton de problemas que me tira Android Studio 3.1.3
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te voy a recomendar que si estás empezando crees tu proyecto con las herramientas que te propone Android Studio, siguiendo el *wizard* paso por paso. Luego puedes ir modificando las `Activity` e incorporando cosas según vayas aprendiendo y comprendiendo cómo funciona cada elemento.

Comment: Hola @FranCode, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Esta misma pregunta se ha realizado varias veces en el sitio en las últimas semanas. Lee [ask] y sigue los consejos que encontrarás allí. Completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y su funcionamiento general.

Answer (score 0):

Es un problema que suele dar esta nueva versión. Para poder visualizar el renderizado te aconsejo que pinches donde dice AppTheme y elijas uno de tipo matrial.

Aquí es donde está el AppTheme.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Elije por ejemplo este de aquí:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esto se solucionará tu problema.

Comment: Adradezco mucho tu ayuda amigo, sin embargo lo acabo de hacer y ni aun asi se soluciona... es increible las fatalidades que cometen estos grandes desarrolladores de Google y lo peor que no se dan prisa a solucionar esto que hacen, en mi caso me estan retrasando mucho en mis projectos en mente y estoy seguro que no soy el unico en esta situacion, Si conoces alguna otra soluciona te agradeceria mucho amigo y grazie mille

Comment: Prueba cambiando la version de android a la version que hayas escogido o haciendo un clean y rebuild del proyecto.